# add tabs which are closable with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, tabs, dynamic-data

hi already i asked this question. but i didn't get perfect solution for this. actually i want **add closeable tabs** which are come by **dynamically**. just see this plugin [demo plugin](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs2_demo.html). pl z help i need very much like dis.
this is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.url_list > li > a').click(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        var url = me.attr('data');
        var ppr = me.html();
        $('.dynamic_content > iframe').remove();
        $('.dynamic_content').append('<iframe src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>');
        $('ul.maintabs') .append('<li><a href="#" data="'+url+'"> ' + ppr + ' </li></li>')
    });
     $('ul.maintabs > li > a').click(function(){
        var re = $(this);
        var vrl = me.attr('data');
             $('.dynamic_content > iframe').remove();
        $('.dynamic_content').append('<iframe src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>');
              });
});
```

Comment: Let me know how http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation does not answer your question, so I have a better idea of what you're asking..

Comment: i seen dis already. but i din't get how can i implement which i want by using this. i want content which is depend on URL only.

Comment: in dis which is  u given duplicates alos possible but i don't want any duplicates. if once der is any existed tab just i want just select dat tab only.

Comment: In order to create a version that only uses the URL, simply replace `"#" + id` on line 57 of the example with a variable containing a url (setting the href to a url instead of #divID will use ajax to load the tab). However, the example is meant for you to learn the jQuery UI implementation of dynamic tabs, not just to be copied and pasted, so I advise that you rewrite the code instead of trying to tweak theircode. As for duplicates, just write your own code to validate it. Let me know if something is still unclear..

Comment: hi this z done, plz where i did mistake.. [jfdemo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkatgoutham7/U3QJ4/7/)